# touch/drag rapid calls

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm creating a shooting game where you touch the screen and the player shoots. The problem I have is that when you touch the screen and keep it down dragging it around it shoots rapid fire. What is the best way to deal with this?

I want the player to be able to hold the finger down and shoot at a steady pace, and on finger up stop shooting.

I was thinking of just using a Timer but I don't think that's very efficient... Any other ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would really like to see more details on how you are implementing the shooting, but let me provide you with a way to accomplish this:

1. In cocos2d, you can use the `CCScheduler` to schedule a method call, instead of using timers. And this is very efficient. You don't have to worry about performance.
2. In the scheduled method, you would check whether the user is still touching the screen, and decide to shoot or not accordingly.

Here is some code to get you started:

**NOTE:** Am using cocos2d v1.0.1 .. in cocos2d v2.0, I think the `CCScheduler` was moved to the `CCDirector`.

```
- (void)init {
    // ...

    [[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] scheduleSelector:@selector(shoot:) forTarget:self interval:0.2f paused:NO];

    // ...
}

- (void)shoot:(ccTime)dt {
    if (userIsTouching) {
        [player shoot];
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want details on my implementation throw me an email and I can explain it there. Give me the details of what you want to know!! 
This was perfect, thank you for your answer!

Comment: lol, no problem, man. I needed details to better elaborate my answer, that's all :) .. But, you figured it out already, so, kudos!